# Visual Basic: Hidemyass regex - I'm totally lost

Tags: vb.net

I'm totally lost guys. I'm new to Regex and after a few days I realize I hate it. Could someone possibly help? I'm trying to make a proxy scraper that scrapes proxies from [this proxy list](http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/) and continues to scrape until there is no more proxies. Can someone help explain where I'm going wrong with my code? Or help me find a better proxy site with easier Regex? Thanks!

Version: VB2012

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class proxy

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim the_request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://gatherproxy.com/proxylist/port/8080")
    Dim the_response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = the_request.GetResponse
    Dim stream_reader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(the_response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim code As String = stream_reader.ReadToEnd
    Dim expression As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,4}")
    Dim mtac As MatchCollection = expression.Matches(code)
    For Each itemcode As Match In mtac
        ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If ListBox1.Items.Count = (0) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please click start to grab proxies!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        Dim S_W As IO.StreamWriter
        Dim itms() As String = {ListBox1.Items.ToString}
        Dim save As New SaveFileDialog
        Dim it As Integer
        save.FileName = "Fresh Proxies"
        save.Filter = "Fresh Proxies (*.txt)|*.txt|ALL Files (*.*)|*.*"
        save.CheckPathExists = True
        save.ShowDialog(Me)
        S_W = New IO.StreamWriter(save.FileName)
        For it = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            S_W.WriteLine(ListBox1.Items.Item(it))
        Next
        S_W.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub proxy_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You'd have to tell us what problem you're actually having.

Comment: @hometoast The problem is the scraper does absolutely nothing. I think the Regex is incorrect.

Comment: Updated my original post, I hope it's a little more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: Simply don’t use regex for an HTML scraper, you’re in for a world of pain. The right tool is a HTML parser. For .NET, there’s the HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Could you maybe help me fix up the code or something or show me an example code?

Comment: No one here who can help...?

Answer (score -1):

Your regex is good, but HideMyAss proxies are "hidden" from proxy parsers.

If you check HTML code from HideMyAss proxy, you'll figure out what i want to say.